# vardump don't work correctly in CI

Tags: codeigniter, var-dump

My controller:

```
function search()
    {
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $this->membership_model->search();

    }
```

Model:

```
function search()
    {
    $q = $this->db->get('feeds');
    var_dump($q);
    }
```

Why var_dump it returns me this:

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#19 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> resource(57) of type (mysql link persistent) ["result_id"]=> resource(68) of type (mysql result) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(325) ["row_data"]=> NULL }
```

It is normal? it not supposed to display me another format of data? Array...etc[]=>[]

Answer (score 1):

to display the data you should write:

```
var_dump($q->result());
```

because:

```
$this->db->get();
```

returns an object from `class CI_DB_mysql_result`. which has the following fields in it:

```
$conn_id, $result_id, $result_array,
 $result_object, $custom_result_object, $current_row, $num_rows, $row_data
```

which you are seeing in your `var_dump`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the query result into an array of items or object of items

```
var_dump($q->result());
```

or

```
var_dump($q->result_array());
```

Using array is less memory consuming